# python glob.glob not working any more, return an empty list

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I am running in a very, strange case... Yesterday I wrote a little script. It's goal is to check one condition in a file based on another file. It worked as intended. But since this morning, it doesn't. I haven't changed anything to the best of my knowledge. the code doesn't throw any error. I think the culprit is glob.glob

```
for file in glob.glob('*private.vcf.gz'):
    seen = False
    vcf = VCF(file)
    print("test")
    if not (file == "controlH.g.vcf.gz" or file == "output.g.vcf.gz"):
        sample_name = file.split('.')[0]
        out = "{}.FalsePositiveRefCallPurged.vcf".format(sample_name)
        w = Writer(out, vcf)
        for v in vcf:
            seen = False
            ref = VCF('output.g.vcf.gz')
            for r in ref:
                if seen :
                    break
                if not seen:
                    if v.CHROM == r.CHROM:
                        if v.start == r.start or v.start > r.start and v.start < r.end:
                            if r.FILTER == "RefCall":
                                continue#print(str(v))
                            else:
                                w.write_record(v)
                            seen = True
        w.close()
```

Indeed, when simply running

```
glob.glob('.*private.vcf.gz')
```

I get an empty list. 
Here is the output of bash

```
ls *.private.vcf.gz
D2A1.private.vcf.gz  D3A1.private.vcf.gz  D5B3.private.vcf.gz  H2C3.private.vcf.gz  H4C2.private.vcf.gz
D2B3.private.vcf.gz  D4A3.private.vcf.gz  H2A3.private.vcf.gz  H4A4.private.vcf.gz  H5A3.private.vcf.gz
```

So I am sure the files are there ... I really don't understand why suddenly glob.glob has troubles finding them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appearst that a direactory

```
/.ipynb_checkpoints
```

was created and my notebook using it as its default directory...